# Why can't I (or how can I) save the output of brew doctor with pipes?

Tags: ruby, homebrew

I'm not sure just how specific this is, but when I run 'brew doctor' I see some error messages. If I want to save those messages I run `brew doctor > brewErrors.txt`. I see the errors in my terminal but if I `cat brewErrors.txt` I just get a file with a few inlines. Is this a more general issue (say of Ruby or some kind of library/method of reporting) or a super narrow one? And for the future, if I ever encounter this how can I work around/fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `>` redirects `STDOUT` and generally error messages appear on `STDERR`. Every unix process has 3 file descriptors open by default: `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR`. You're redirecting `STDOUT` but should be redirecting either just `STDERR` with

```
brew doctor 2> brewErrors.txt
```

or both `STDERR` and `STDOUT` with

```
brew doctor &> brewErrors.txt
```

This is the same whether you're using a `bash` shell or the newer `zsh` shell.

Comment: While it's a simple work-around, the purist in me wants to point out that `brew doctor` is not using STDERR appropriately. STDERR would be for errors of the `brew doctor` command, not for the _standard output_ (STDOUT) of the command which is what the output from `brew doctor` is. It's understandable that this causes confusion.